# timstamp from string to timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, timestamp

i have the followoing format of a timestamp which is saved as string.

```js
2022-09-15T11:07:28.872
```

I've tried to convert it to timestamp like this

```js
PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S",JSON_VALUE(DATA,'$.payload.onHoldUntil'))
```

but i get the following error

```js
Mismatch between format character '-' and string character 'T'
```

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The format string you provide in the `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` function should align to the format of your string.  In your case it does not as you are missing a T and the milliseconds.

Try the following:

```
select '2022-09-15T11:07:28.872' as s_ts
  , PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%R:%E3S', '2022-09-15T11:07:28.872')
```

Comment: Thanks!
Where can I find the explanation behind these format ? 
I was tryig to find a correct format in the google search but I could only find the standard ones.

Comment: See the link here: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time